# ListView Alternate colors

Tags: android, listview, colors, alternate

I need to make a ListView with alternate color.

code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if(position %2==0)
  {
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  }
  return view;
}
```

but I don't know how to use it in my Adapter:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, propositions, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
    new String[] {"Date", "Trajet"},
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, 
    android.R.id.text2});
lvTrajets.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can someone help me about how to do this please ?

Comment: just override getView for your adapter

Comment: You have to write your own adapter and override getView

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `getView` for the adapter

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, propositions, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
new String[] {"Date", "Trajet"},
new int[] { android.R.id.text1, 
android.R.id.text2})
    {
        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
             if(position %2==0)
             {
                  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             }
             else
             {
                  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
             }

            return v;
        }


    };
```

Comment: It makes my application crash

Comment: @user3507621 you can check a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905041/why-cant-i-click-a-button-in-a-listview-using-simpleadapter-in-android/22905116#22905116 but no background is set

Comment: nullPointerException line 90. It's the v.setBackColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: @user3507621  `v` is null. post the full code updated

Comment: @user3507621 if you follow the post properly it should work else post the updated code

Answer (score 0):

This is my get view. I change one image background, you just change parent layout color for particular position from your logic `if(position %2==0)` simple here. I only give you trick for this, not complete code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.devicesnameshow_item, null);
        }


        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deviceimage);

        Resources res = v.getResources();
        String mDrawableName = data[position].umt;
        int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);




          if(position %2==0)
        {
            imgIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]));// u can give any color i just take it from my array 
        } else {
            imgIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]));// u can give any color i just take it from my array 
        }




        }
         return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing alternate colors in the `ListView` Implement your `getView()` method of  `Adapter` in the following way

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if(convertView==null){
//Initialize the convertView and all its view's
}
  if(position %2==0)
  {
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  }else{
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
  }
  return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 call from your activity :
ListAdapteradapter = new ListAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.listmain, from, to);

ListAdapter class:

public class ListAdapter  extends SimpleAdapter {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

     View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 

        if (position % 2 == 1)
        {

             view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue); 


        } 
        else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lavendar);
        }
        return view;  
        }



}
```