# android: how do I change a field in an array of JSONObject when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, json

I have a `ListView` that consists the items from my array of `JSONObject` in the server. In every item, I have a button. I want to update a field in the where the button is clicked. How do I do this?

**I have this json file :**

[
  {
    "notif_id": 1,
    "Event": "Trial Event 1",
    "start_date": "/Date(1485277800000)/",
    "end_date": "/Date(1485294900000)/",
    "feedback": 0
  },
  {
    "notif_id": 2,
    "Event": "Trial Event 2",
    "start_date": "/Date(1485376200000)/",
    "end_date": "/Date(1485385500000)/",
    "feedback": 0
  },
  {
    "notif_id": 3,
    "Event": "Trial Event 3",
    "start_date": "/Date(1485534000000)/",
    "end_date": "/Date(1485543300000)/",
    "feedback": 0
  }
]

**UPDATED**

This is where I get the value of my fields from JSON file..

```
//looping events
                for(int i=0; i < events.length(); i++){
                     JSONObject e = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    // String notif= e.getString("notif_id");
                        String Event = e.getString("Event");
                        //start_date parsing
                        String start_date= e.getString("start_date");
                        start_date= start_date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
                        long start_time= Long.parseLong(start_date);
                        Date startdate= new Date(start_time);
                        temp_start = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startdate).toString();
                        start_date= temp_start; 

                        //end_date parsing
                        String end_date = e.getString("end_date");
                        end_date= end_date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
                        long end_time= Long.parseLong(end_date);
                        Date enddate= new Date(end_time);
                        temp_end = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(enddate).toString();
                        end_date= temp_end;

                     // tmp hash map for single event
                        HashMap<String, String> eventtemp = new HashMap<String, String>();

                     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        eventtemp.put("Event", Event);
                        eventtemp.put("start_date", start_date); 
                        eventtemp.put("end_date", end_date);
                       // eventtemp.put("notif_id", notif);

                     // adding event to event list
                       feedList.add(eventtemp); 
                }
```

And this is how I put them to the Listview item:

```
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    HomeActivity.this, feedList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"Event" , "start_date",
                    "end_date"}, new int[]{R.id.event,
                    R.id.start_date, R.id.end_date});

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
```

I want to change the feedback of the respective event where the button is clicked. 
Can someone please help with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to update it in server?

Comment: Yes I want to update in server.

Comment: You need a webservice to send new data to server... Do you have one?

Comment: My json file is located in a separate environment (VS). As I am linking my web app to my android app. I connect to the location of my json file through HttpHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that you store that JSON file in a String called `data`.

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);   // convert data (String) to JSONArray

// On button clicked, change the value
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get first item from jsonArray
            // For secondButton and thirdButton, adjust the index
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            jsonObject.put("notif_id", 1);
            jsonObject.put("Event", "Trial Event 1 Success");
            jsonObject.put("feedback", 1);
            jsonArray.put(0, jsonObject);
        }
    });
```

And don't forget to surround with try/catch to handle JSONException.

**EDIT - 1**

If you are using ListView, inside its adapter class, you should have a method called:
`getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)`.
Then, you can update JSON String inside this method:

```
holder.btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
            jsonObject.put("notif_id", 1);
            jsonObject.put("Event", "Trial Event 1 Success");
            jsonObject.put("feedback", 1);
            jsonArray.put(position, jsonObject);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT - 2**

Okay, seems like your main problem is not how to update JSON values at button click, but how to access a button inside ListView so you can update JSON values based on a button clicked at specified position of the list (am I right?).

Then, you should override `getView` method, and to make it simple (so you do not need to create a separate adapter class for your ListView), you can do:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this, feedList,
    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"Event", "start_date", "end_date"},
    new int[]{R.id.event, R.id.start_date, R.id.end_date}) {
        @Override
        public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Button btUpdate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
            btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        // data is String type you stored your JSON file
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
                        jsonObject.put("notif_id", 1);
                        jsonObject.put("Event", "Trial Event 1 Success");
                        jsonObject.put("feedback", 1);
                        jsonArray.put(position, jsonObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    };
```

My resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905116/4088357

Comment: Thanks for your response Janice . But I want to simultaneously get the index of the button clicked. Like if I click the first one it would modify the first one, but second if I clicked the second, and so on. In my xml file there is only one button and the textviews that represents the field. And they are being used in Listview.

Comment: My array of JSONObject is being shown in a Listview together with the button. @JaniceKartika

Comment: ok @Nnana I have edited the answer. But with that approach you should pass the JSON String to the adapter, otherwise you should create an interface.

Comment: it seems to be not working.. I have this error message in my LogCat:java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That error is too general, please update your question and post the adapter class + activity/fragment class

Comment: Thanks for helping me @JaniceKartika. I already edited my question and I made it more descriptive and complete.

Comment: hey @Nnana, so you do not yet create your own custom adapter class?

Comment: Thank you @JaniceKartika. You really got my point however I still get the same error in the logcat. I don't know what's wrong with this anymore.