# Checking column value when SimpleCursorAdapter is adding values from table to listView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, simplecursoradapter

in my table I have column name `"FAVOURITE"` which has value 0 or 1 (false/true). When I'm adding the values from table to my `listView` I would like to check the value in `FAVOURITE` column and add the heart emoji if value is 1 or empty space if value is 0. I'm using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to add my data to list view.

Here is a fragment where I'm adding values to `listView`:

```
cursor = db.query("SERIAL",new String[]{"_id","NAME","SERVICE","SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"},null,null,null,null,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_custom_list,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"NAME","SERVICE","SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"}, //"Ulubione" mean "Favourite"
            new int[]{R.id.textNazwa,R.id.textSerwis,R.id.Sezon,R.id.aktualnyOdcinek,R.id.iloscOdcinkow, R.id.Ulubione},
            0);
    listViewSeriale.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

And full code of this class:

```
public class BazaDanych extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjektSQLiteOpenHelper bazaDanych;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private ListView listViewSeriale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baza_danych);

        listViewSeriale = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSeriale);
        try {
            bazaDanych = new ProjektSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
            db = bazaDanych.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Baza danych niedostępna", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listViewOrganizacje, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BazaDanych.this, BazaDanychAktualizacja.class);
                intent.putExtra(BazaDanychAktualizacja.EXTRA_ORGANIZACJA_ID, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        listViewSeriale.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BazaDanych.this, BazaDanychDopisz.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cursor = db.query("SERIAL", new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "SERVICE", "SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_custom_list,
                    cursor,
                    new String[]{"NAME", "SERVICE", "SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"},
                    new int[]{R.id.textNazwa, R.id.textSerwis, R.id.Sezon, R.id.aktualnyOdcinek, R.id.iloscOdcinkow, R.id.Ulubione}, //"Ulubione" mean "Favourite"
                    0);
            listViewSeriale.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void odejmijOdcinekZListy(View view) {
        TextView serwTest = findViewById(R.id.textSerwis);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Odejmij odcinek" + serwTest.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Maybe I should read columns after create list view and check all elements by `findViewById(R.id.Ulubione).getText and .setText` but how I can do this with `listView`?
Bump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by accident in this post [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905116/13039704)

My `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cursor = db.query("SERIAL", new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "SERVICE", "SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_custom_list,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME", "SERVICE", "SEASON", "CURRENT_EPISODE", "EPISODES", "FAVOURITE"},
                new int[]{R.id.textNazwa, R.id.textSerwis, R.id.Sezon, R.id.aktualnyOdcinek, R.id.iloscOdcinkow, R.id.Ulubione}, //"Ulubione" mean "Favourite"
                0) {

            // XDDDDD
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Ulubione);
                if (Integer.parseInt(tx.getText().toString()) == 1)
                    tx.setText("❤️");
                else
                    tx.setText("♡");
                return v;
            }
        };
        listViewSeriale.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```